# How do I find the best response for a Stackberg duopoly with price leadership, specifically for the question below

Tags: price, model

Consider a market served by two firms, firm $1$ and firm $2$. Suppose that the (inverse) demands for the two firms are given by
$P_1=1-q_1-aq_2$
$P_2=1-q_2-aq_1$ with $a$ belongs to $(0,1)$.
In addition, suppose that the two firms face the same constant marginal costs equal to $c$ where $0<c<1$
Suppose that both firms strategically choose prices to maximize own profits and firm $1$ chooses its price before firm $2$. Using
• Derive and describe the best response functions of the two firms
• Derive and describe the prices, quantities and profits in equilibrium

Comment: You first write down the profit functions for both firms.  Then you calculate for a given $q_1$ the value $q_2$ that maximizes the profit of firm $2$. This will give you $q_2$ as a function of $q_1$. Plug the solution into the profit function of firm $1$ and solve the resulting profit maximization problem in a single variable, $q_1$. This gives you the choice of $q_1$. Plug it into your previous solution for firm 2 to get theiroptimal quantity. The rest should be easy.

Comment: Have you checked this post in wikipedia about Stackelberg competition? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackelberg_competition

It is simple and veryhelpful!